# How to hide OAuth credentals stored in an Angular app?

Tags: angular, api, oauth

I'm working with an Angular 7 app which performs API calls on another server. This API needs an Oauth1 authorization.

My concern is that OAuth1 credentials are perfeclty visible in the `dist/main.js` file, and obviously I want to hide this information.

I first thought about encoding credentials with any encoding method, and then decode them before performing an API call. But this solution is ineffective, since any code of a front-end application is accessible, and the encoding/decoding method is no exception.

I also thought about storing credentials in a database on the front-end server side, directly accessed by the Angular app, but I'm wondering if it's not a little bit "too much" for my needs.

Currently, credentials are attributes of an helper class:

```
export class OAuth1Authorization implements IAuthorization {
    private token = {
        consumerKey: '...',
        consumerSecret: '...',
        accessToken: '...',
        tokenSecret: '...'
    };
    private signatureMethod = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    private version = '1.0';
    private nonce;
    // ...
}
```

One last word, I want to be really clear on the fact that my usecase is *not* storing a token returned by a remote server after a username/password authentification, for example.

My needs are really to store in a secure way (eg. so that the connection information can't be accessed in clear text!) 4 tokens, that should be known in advance, both on the front-end and on the back-end side, and which won't change for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, OAuth1 was not designed for modern JS apps: the secret is required for the authentication and as you noticed, there is no fully bullet-proof way to store it client side.

No matter where you hide it, how you encode it, it will get decoded at some point by your app and can be trivially retrieved with the debugger.

The OAuth1 documentation page (https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/advanced/Web.html) suggests the use of a minimal proxy which knows the secrets and can perform the authentication when your web client sends it the non-secret parameters.